# Redirect issue - Checkout redirect to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, upgrade, redirect

I have a problem when updating one of my sites from `1.9.3.0` to `1.9.3.3`. All my other sites are working fine.

Once updated (tried via SSH, FTP and Magento Connect Downloader) the onepage checkout just redirects back to the cart page. It does this irrespective of whether Formkey is `enabled/disabled`.

Ive tried many fixes, including adding formkey code to older extensions. I've even uninstalled all the extensions (via **Magento Connect Downloader**) without luck.

How do I go about troubleshooting this, and finding the cause of the problem?

The site has been live since 2012, and perhaps there may be some legacy theme/plugin elements causing the issue?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the fresh magento files of your version
2. Upload again through FTP unless you haven't customized any of your magento files before.

**Note :** That action might crash your files or functionalities